# how does modulus on a while loop executes?

Tags: javascript

I need help understanding this solution for getting a prime factor. this is the code
[demo](https://repl.it/CcgA)

```
function getMaxPrimeFactor (n) {
    var temp = n;
    for(var i = 2; i < temp; i++) {
        while (temp % i === 0) {
            temp /= i;
        }
    }   
    console.log(temp);
}

getMaxPrimeFactor(13195);
```

I understand the for loop but I don't know what's going on the while loop and the division, how did it get an output of 29?

Comment: modulus gives you the remainder of the division so it runs the while loop until the remainder is non-zero.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks, ok, I console.log(i) and it's 2 up to 29, meanwhile the temp is 13195. how does this code executes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what is going on:

The point of the `for` loop is to try every single divisor between 2 and the current value of `temp` which starts out equal to the original number.

The point of the `while` loop is to take each one of those divisors and try them as many times as possible.  As long as the remainder comes up `0` meaning it divided evenly, then keep dividing and reduce `temp` to the result of the division each time.

So, `while (temp % i === 0)` means to keep running the while loop as long as `temp` divides by `i` evenly with no remainder.  The `%` modulus operator computes the remainder after division.

Here's a more instrumented version that when you run it shows you a bit more about what is going on:

```js
function getMaxPrimeFactor (n) {
    var temp = n;
    for(var i = 2; i < temp; i++) {
        while (temp % i === 0) {
            temp /= i;
            console.log("factor=",i,", ",temp*i,"/",i, "=",temp);
        }
    }   
    console.log("remaining factor=",temp);
}

getMaxPrimeFactor(13195);
```

Comment: Added instrumented snippet to show you what it's doing.

Comment: Thank you! you answered more than asked. +rep

Answer (score 1):

Here `while` is checking if value of `temp % i` is `0` (i.e. if `temp` is divisible with `i`). If this condition is `true` it will store `temp / i` in `temp`

So when the `while` condition is true

```
i   temp   (temp % i)  new_temp_value(temp/i)
5   13195  0           2639
7   2639   0           377
13  377    0           29
29  29     -           - //for loop stops here since `i < temp` condition doesn't satisfy.
```

Last temp value is `29`

So if we consider only `i` value from above, we get `5, 7, 13, 29` which are factors of `13195`.

i.e. `5 * 7 * 13 * 29 = 13195`

So the max value in factors is `29`.